# C# Display Images (in run-time vs. on Load)

Tags: c#, image, winforms

My App allows user to see Images, one at a time.
There are 2 buttons ("previous" & "next") so the user can cycle through the Images. The Image paths are stored in XML.

When the App loads I can either create a variable `var myImage = Image.FromFile(path)` for each image, and add each Image to a List of Images, and retrieve from the List as the user presses Previous or Next, with `myImageBox.Image = List_Images[x];`

..or.. just store the paths to the Images in a List of strings, and retrieve the paths from the List with `myImageBox.Image = Image.FromFile(List_Strings[x]);`

Since the user might cycle back and forth through the Images i was wondering what performance concerns there might be between storing all the Images as Image variables vs. storing paths as strings. Will it be slower to use Image.FromFile() each time a button is pressed? or Is storing 300-500 images going to be a bigger issue for the memory?

[The Images are varied Resolution and 300 pixels Wide and 250 pixels Height]

Comment: 300-500, I'd go loading the files each time. Caching that many in memory will result in very slow startup times. Depends on the PC specs though. Generally speaking navigation back will be a fraction of forward navigation so that is the main reason for loading each time. You could try this with Microsoft Picture Viewer and I'm pretty sure they load from disk each time.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks. I was thinking to just store as Image variables because i thought it would be faster, but considering your thoughts i think i will just load from File each time instead. Is there a threshold, like if only 50 pics then it would be better? How do i select you as the answerer? ( i see by the auto-correct that 'answerer' its not a word but it should be:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're app is run on a x86 machine then the processes address space is 2gig max. That's the basic start of how you'd work out the threshold.

An image/bitmap is an unmanaged resource so you have to use "using" or explicitly Dispose for each resource, having too many in memory isn't a good thing. They aren't like value types stored on the thread stack or reference types stored in the managed heap.

If there were 50 or so 3mb images I think I would consider caching (particularly if they were frames in a video where navigating backwards was a very common operation) otherwise I would load from disk. Most PC's come with SSDs these days anyway which is almost like loading from RAM.

You could write some benchmarks, the end-users milage will vary though. If 300-500 is a constant and PC specs is a variable, the better approach is load from disk.